# Handle comma data in csv file in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a csv which is somewhat like  foo,bar. This must go into a single column but what I see is it goes into a separate column as it is comma delimited.

How do we handle this ? I also added double quotes "foo,bar" and put the escape character as double quotes(") in source but I get the data with the double quotes in the final data.

Please suggest how do we handle this situation in ADF ?

Comment: You have added double quotes ("foo,bar") to your source and escape character as double quote (") for the source dataset. What do you mean by "I get data with double quotes in final data"?

Comment: Basically i just need the data as foo,bar in one column in csv sink. Ignore the double quotes which I added manually to make it a single entity.

Comment: So, is it possible for you to manipulate the source data to add double quotes for every value?

Comment: No I cant manipulate it. I just wanted to know if there is an option in ADF where we can handle this situation.

Answer (score 0):

> Handle comma data in csv file in Azure Data Factory

If your source file has data which contain `comma(,)` in it and you set the **Column delimiter** also as `comma(,)` then while reading file it will consider different column wherever it finds `comma(,)` in data.

**To solve this there are two methods:**

1. You can change the Column delimiter for file like **Semicolon (;), Pipe (|), Tab (\t) etc;** then it will not consider the comma in data as different column.
2. Add **Quotes ("")** to data where it contains comma
   e.g, "foo,bar" and set **Quote character** as `Double quote (")` so it will consider it as single value

> I also added double quotes "foo,bar" and put the escape character as double quotes(") in source but I get the data with the double quotes in the final data.

To handle this set **Escape character** as `No escape character` and **Quote character** as `No quote character` in the **Sink dataset**

- **Sink dataset setting:**
  [image]
- **Sample data:**
  [image]
- **Output**
  [image]

Answer (score 0):

Check your CSV file. Check for double quotes around any field that may have a comma. If there are double quotes, use the Quote and Escape character options as shown.
[image]